# Image Hover effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a image hover effect it hovers well. but i need to be just like the bottom.. as of right now everything is hidden until you hover then it shows... I have tried to modify the margin and padding with no luck

[Demo Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDnzX.jpg)

```css
    .hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
 top: auto;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 1em;
 height: 4.75em;
 background: #79FAC4;
 color: #3c4a50;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 margin: 50px 0 0 0;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.hovereffect a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}


.hovereffect p.icon-links a {
 float: right;
 color: #3c4a50;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:hover,
.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:focus {
 color: #252d31;
}

.hovereffect h2,
.hovereffect p.icon-links a {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
}

.hovereffect p.icon-links a span:before {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


.hovereffect:hover .overlay,
.hovereffect:hover h2,
.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
 transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:first-child {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Effect 10</h2>
                <p class="icon-links">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the `translate` properties in the CSS:

```
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 4.75em;
    background: #79FAC4;
    color: #3c4a50;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
}
```

I changed the above to `translate3d(0,50%,0);` the higher the Y (middle) percentage, the more the overlay is hidden.

```css
.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
 top: auto;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 1em;
 height: 4.75em;
 background: #79FAC4;
 color: #3c4a50;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
}

.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-10%,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 margin: 50px 0 0 0;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.hovereffect a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}


.hovereffect p.icon-links a {
 float: right;
 color: #3c4a50;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:hover,
.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:focus {
 color: #252d31;
}

.hovereffect h2,
.hovereffect p.icon-links a {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
}

.hovereffect p.icon-links a span:before {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


.hovereffect:hover .overlay,
.hovereffect:hover h2,
.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
 transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.icon-links a:first-child {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Effect 10</h2>
                <p class="icon-links">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```